solana wallet phanton hacked can't seem to do anything anymore
I got my solana wallet hacked, using sanctum. 2 of my pets was drained and rest of my coins I cant really do anything. can someone help me????
https://solscan.io/tx/5rk6M11SLo7ZHwjW2SmAJkTzqbPiyW5gGUpbALTVzT3g5UWgxtEDAjJXuWM3m1wSqRMBgqPdptpokCUAsLrDM4dm
